# Change value in nested struct, array, struct in a Spark dataframe using PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

So I have this spark dataframe with following schema:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- elements: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- created: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- items: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- field: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- fieldId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- fieldtype: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- from: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- fromString: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- tmpFromAccountId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- tmpToAccountId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- to: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- toString: string (nullable = true)
```

For this case, I want to change value inside "items" elements (field, fieldId, etc.) using defined value ("Issue") - without caring if it is empty or already filled. So it should be from:

```
+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id     | elements                                                                       |
+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|ABCD-123|[2023-01-16T20:25:30.875+0700, 5388402, [[field, , status,,,,, 23456, Yes]]]    |
+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

To:

```
+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id     | elements                                                                                                 |
+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|ABCD-123|[2023-01-16T20:25:30.875+0700, 5388402, [[Issue, Issue, Issue, Issue, Issue, Issue, Issue, Issue, Issue]]]|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I already try using this script in python file, but it didn't work:

```
replace_list = ['field', 'fieldtype', 'fieldId', 'from', 'fromString', 'to', 'toString', 'tmpFromAccountId', 'tmpToAccountId']

# Didn't work 1
for col_name in replace_list: df = df.withColumn(f"items.element.{col_name}", lit("Issue"))

# Didn't work 2
for col_name in replace_list: df = df.withColumn("elements.items.element", struct(col(f"elements.items.element.*"), lit("Issue").alias(f"{col_name}")))
```

In this case, **I'm using Spark version 2.4.8**. I don't want to use explode method since I want to avoid join dataframes. Is it possible to perform this kind of operation directly in spark? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you want your question to be answered more quickly, it's always best to try and make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That way, your question is more useful to you (quicker response) and the reviewers (easier to answer). Please edit your question and add the necessary. In this case, you should add an example of your whole input dataframe and what your output should look like.

Comment: @Koedlt Hi there, thank you so much for your comments. I already edit the question. Hopefully this time this should be very clear. Thank you so much for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I simplified your example a bit, let's assume your dataset is called `df`, containing this data:

```
+---------------------------------------------+
|elements                                     |
+---------------------------------------------+
|{1, [{field, fieldId, from, fromString}]}    |
|{2, [{field2, fieldId2, from2, fromString2}]}|
+---------------------------------------------+
```

and this schema:

```
root
 |-- elements: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- items: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- field: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- fieldId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- from: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- fromString: string (nullable = true)
```

An approach to get to your desired result, is to extract the `keys` of all elements inside the array, do the same for `values`, then concatenate them, as below:

```
df
  .withColumn("keys", expr("transform(elements.items, x -> json_object_keys(to_json(x)))"))
  .withColumn("values", expr("transform(keys, x -> transform(x, y -> 'Issue'))"))
  .withColumn("final", expr("transform(keys, (x, i) -> map_from_arrays(keys[i], values[i]))"))
```

The final output looks like:

```
+---------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|elements                                     |final                                                                   |
+---------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{1, [{field, fieldId, from, fromString}]}    |[{field -> Issue, fieldId -> Issue, from -> Issue, fromString -> Issue}]|
|{2, [{field2, fieldId2, from2, fromString2}]}|[{field -> Issue, fieldId -> Issue, from -> Issue, fromString -> Issue}]|
+---------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Hopefully this is what you want, since it's a bit hard to help without providing examples. Good luck!

Comment: Hi there, thank you so much for your comments. I already edit the question. Hopefully this time this should be very clear. Thank you so much for your suggestions.